# @PostFilter does not work with Spring @Aspect

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-aop, spring-security-acl

I am trying to do something like this:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
class CustomAspect {
    @Pointcut("within(@com.example.security.Check *)")
    public void classAnnotatedWithCheck() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("publicMethod() && classAnnotatedWithCheck()")
    public void publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithCheck() {}

    @Around(value = "publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithCheck()")
    public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        return executeWithFilter(point);
    }

    @PostFilter(value = "hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
    private Object executeWithFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        return point.proceed();
    }
}
```

Aspects work well, but the last method `executeWithFilter` is done without filtering. At the same time, filtering works if I add `@PostFilter(value = "hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")` to a regular service method. Is it even possible to use `@PostFilter` in aspects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring [Method Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#nsa-method-security) is AOP based.

Also , from the Spring AOP reference documentation : [Declaring an Aspect](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-at-aspectj)

> In Spring AOP, aspects themselves cannot be the targets of advice from
> other aspects. The @Aspect annotation on a class marks it as an aspect
> and, hence, excludes it from auto-proxying.

Security advices should get applied on a bean for providing `@PostFilter` method security , which is not possible on an aspect. In short Spring security will not work on an aspect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Probably have to implement a custom permission checks.

Comment: I just notice know that you do "word , word" on purpose interesting